# Could game cartridges or flash-drives be damaged by the magnet in an external hard-drive?

Tags: hard-drive, flash

I found out that I had stored one of my external hard-drives right on top of a bunch of Nintendo DS and GameBoy Advance cartridges and a few flash-drives for a while.

Is there a chance they could have been damaged by the magnets inside the drive?

Comment: The drive had no power. Nothing could was damaged.  Of course a drive out in the open, outside of a anti-static bag, could have been damaged for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem for a few reasons:

- [Game cartridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROM_cartridge) are not magnetic media; they store the game data in a [ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory) (read-only memory) which is stored electronically in a chip/[IC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit).
- Flash-drives are not magnetic media; they store their data in, well, [flash-media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_media). Go figure.
- The magnet in the hard-drive, while powerful, has a very sharp drop-off which gives it an extremely short range. That means that you would have to put the magnet directly on top of a magnetic media like a floppy disk to affect it. The distance caused by the mere physical dimensions of the drive and all the shielding from the metal casing prevent the magnetic field from penetrating far enough to damage anything.

There’s [several](https://superuser.com/questions/323036/can-screwdrivers-with-magnetic-tips-cause-damage-to-electronics) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/113430/what-computer-components-are-currently-vulnerable-to-magnets) [here](https://superuser.com/questions/334782/how-is-the-interference-of-magnetic-field-of-adjacent-platters-managed) about the [risk of magnets](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:superuser.com%20magnet%20drive).

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have a problem. GBA and DS cartridges are some sort of ROM technology and not susceptible to anything short of smashing them with the external HD.